# Why do we assume the ring to be torsion free when dealing with formal logarithms in the context of formal group laws?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $F$ be a formal group over a ring $R$. Why do we require that $R$ has no additive torsion before we discuss formal logarithms?

Comment: What is meant here by additive torsion?

Comment: I'm guessing you meant $F(x,F(x,\ldots)) = 0$?

Comment: I mean if $a$ is a non-zero element of the ring $R$ then $a+a+...+a$ is never zero for any number of terms.
(Please note that the question has been edited. There was a mistake. I meant an arbitrary ring $R$ and not the real numbers.)

Comment: My guess is that it allows you to nicely define formal power series without worrying about terms "unnaturally" being zero. For instance in a formal power series in $x$, you'll have something like $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots$ where the $a_i$ are in $R$. Now what could be the case is that $a_0 = 0$, $a_1$ is fixed and $a_n = n.a_1$ for $n>1$. This is a perfectly reasonable formal power series, but if you have torsion, then $a_n = 0$ for sufficiently large $n$. Meaning that your power series is actually just a polynomial. This could get in the way when developing a series for the logarithm.

Comment: Maybe the simplest way to put it is that it lets you develop a theory of formal power series in the broadest sense possible with the least amount of hiccups.